# free-jqgrid: getLocalRow return false in free-jqgrid4.13.6

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

[image]We were using below code in jqgrid 4.3. Now I am upgrading to 4.13.6. The below code was working in 4.3, but in 4.13, it return false... Any help please...

```
var grid = $("#myGrid").jqGrid('getRowData');
$.each(grid, function(key, value) {
    selectedRow = key+1;
    var rowData = $("#myGrid").jqGrid('getLocalRow', selectedRow);
});
```

I am not using any id while filling my grid. datatype: json,  rownumbers: true.

When I debug, I see the ID of each rows are 'jqg41', 'jqg42' etc... And sometimes it is 'jqg61', 'jqg62' etc... It is a random number which is appended after 'jqg'

some more code (but not completed code)

```
$grid.jqGrid({
                    datatype: 'json',
                    url: 'myUrl/byFileId.do?custId='+custId,
                    mtype: 'GET',
                    ajaxSubgridOptions: { async: false },
                    colNames:[ col1, col2 ...],
                    colModel:[    
                        . . .
                        . . .
                        . . .
                    ],  
                    headertitles:true,
                    rowNum:999,
                    rowList:[],
                    pager: '',
                    records: 1000,
                    pgbuttons : false,
                    viewrecords : false,
                    pgtext : null,
                    pginput : false,
                    gridview:true,
                    ignoreCase:true,
                    rownumbers:true,
                    sortname: 'invdate',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    sortorder: 'desc',
                    multiselect: true, 
                    caption: "Customer Search Result",
                    height: '100%',
                    editurl: 'clientArray',
                    autoencode: true,
                    loadonce: true,
                    multiselectWidth: 30,
                    width: rmtPageTitleWidth,
                    viewsortcols : [true,'vertical',true],
                    onSortCol: function (index, idxcol, sortorder) {
                        rowIdAndNoOfRowPair = [];
                        if (this.p.lastsort >= 0 && this.p.lastsort !== idxcol
                                && this.p.colModel[this.p.lastsort].sortable !== false) {
                            $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).find(">div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico").show();
                        }
                    },
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but the code, which you post is absolutely wrong.If `key` is the rowid, then `key+1` s not.  What shell it do? Do you need to get the data of **selected** rows or all local data of the grid? Why you don't specify the rowid? Which data and which grid you use? By the way, I started my answer on your previous question with the suggestion to set `key: true` property in `customerId` column, which inform jqGrid to use the values from `customerId` column as rowids. **Your code still wrong any you should explain, what should it do.**

Comment: I recommend you to read [the article](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#the_first_grid), where I explain what is rowid. See [the picture](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#grid-internal-div) and the explanation below.

Comment: @Oleg: in jqgrid 4.3, the 'key' always gives me 0, but the id of the row starts from '1'. that is why I did "key+1'. Now to your second question, I can't make customer id as key=true, because I can have multiple customer of same id in the grid. What IS want: I want to go through each row (both select and non-selected) and get data, then I could apply logic with those data in javascript and then send to backend. now I am wondering why it is creating the id of row as 'jqg<some random number>

Comment: I repeat, that what you explain is the automatic generation of generation of rowids **if the input data was wrong** and didn't contained and id information. You should never have any assumption about the algorithm of auto-generated ids. I still don't understand your description. You should never post such minimal fragment of code. I can only guess that you mean the grid with `datatype: "json"` and `loadonce: true` like in your previous question. You don't need to "go through each row". You can just use `$("#myGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")` to get the reference to all local data.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
var localData = $("#myGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
```

to get all local data as an array. It's **the reference** to internal data of jqGrid.

**UPDATED:** If the grid is *sorted or filtered* **locally** and want to get the data from all rows in the same order, then you should get `lastSelectedData` parameter instead of `data`. You can force sorting the data locally after loading from the server by usage `forceClientSorting: true` parameter of jqGrid additionally to `loadonce: true`.

The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/akv51mdq/ demonstrates `lastSelectedData` in case of local data, which has no id information. Another demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/Ljejoh21/ do the same with the data loaded from the server at once.