# Export filtered data to CSV from jqgrid

Tags: java, jquery, jqgrid

I am using free jqgrid 4.14 and I need to export the data of the grid into CSV/Excel. I have already made a function which exports all the data to CSV.
I am capturing the data coming from the server and using that data to form the CSV. But here the problem is how will I get only the filtered data from the grid. Is there any default property or function for that?

This is my function -

```
  function convertor (gridData, scopes, ShowLabel, fileTitle,grid_header_column_value,id) {


        scopes.grid_header_columns = scopes.grid_header_column_value[id];
        var bg = "<button class='btnfilter' />";
        for (var i = 0; i < scopes.grid_hidden_columns[id].length; i++) {
            if (includes(scopes.grid_header_columns,scopes.grid_hidden_columns[id][i]) == true) {
                var indexhed = scopes.grid_header_columns.indexOf(scopes.grid_hidden_columns[id][i]);
                scopes.grid_header_columns.splice(indexhed, 1);
            }
        }
        var arrData = typeof gridData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(gridData) : gridData;
        var CSV = '';
        if (ShowLabel) {
            var row = "";
            var count = 0;
            if (fileTitle != "" )
            {
                var htmltext = fileTitle.split(',');
                for (var jj = 0; jj < htmltext.length; jj++)
                {
                    var datacont = document.getElementById(htmltext[jj]);
                    if (datacont == undefined)
                        datacont = '';
                    else
                        datacont = datacont.textContent + '\r\n';
                    CSV += datacont;
                }
            }
            for (var index in arrData[0]) {
                var a = scopes.gridextra.indexOf(index);
                if (a == -1 && scopes.grid_header_columns[count] != undefined) {
                    row += scopes.grid_header_columns[count].replace(bg, "") + ',';
                    count++;
                }
            }
            row = row.slice(0, -1);
            CSV += row + '\r\n';
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {

            var row = "";
            for (var index in arrData[i]) {

                var a = scopes.gridextra.indexOf(index);

                if (a == -1) {
                    if (isNaN(arrData[i][index]) == false) {
                            if(arrData[i][index]<0) {
                                if(arrData[i][index] == -2)
                                    arrValue = '="'+"*"+'"';
                                else
                                    arrValue = '="'+"N/A"+'"';
                            }
                            else
                                var arrValue = arrData[i][index] == null ? "" : '="' + arrData[i][index] + '"';
                    }
                    else
                            var arrValue = arrData[i][index] == null ? "" : '="' + arrData[i][index] + '"';
                        row += arrValue + ',';
                }
            }
            row.slice(0, row.length - 1);
            CSV += row + '\r\n';
        }
        if (CSV == '') {
            growl.error("Invalid data");
            return;
        }
        csvData = CSV;       
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem, then you should to use `lastSelectedData` parameter instead of `data` parameter. The `data` parameter contains original data. The `lastSelectedData` parameter contains the *filtered and sorted* data (all pages). See the demos, which I created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42274864/315935).

Comment: if there is no filtering on the grid then lastSelectedData parameter remains empty?

Comment: @shv22: It could be so depend on the version of free jqGrid, which you use, and from the combination of options, which you use. The behavior was in old versions of free jqGrid. The current code should initialize `lastSelectedData` (see [the lines](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.14.0/js/grid.base.js#L4153-L4154)), but I could imagine that close initializing could need be done in another places of free jqGrid code. Just verify that you use the latest free jqGrid and if you still have uninitialized `lastSelectedData`, then could post me the demo, which reproduce the problem.

Comment: I dont understand I made a demo where it is working fine but not in actual code