# Free jqgrid lastSelectedData extra field

Tags: jquery, export, free-jqgrid

I am exporting the lastSelectedData in my code and it is working OK. However, I am getting a weird additional field in the data set that looks like it is being added by the jqgrid code:

```
undefined:undefined:"jqg33"
```

I am not doing anything unusual in my code. Just getting the data from the grid:

`var gridData = jQuery(self.gridSel).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'lastSelectedData');`

It's easy enough to look for that field and take it out, but before I do that, I thought I would ask about it.

Has anyone else seen this? I am using version 4.14.0.

Comment: Here is a full object in the data array returned from lastSelectedData: {createDate:"2017-06-07 24:00"
creator:"Nathan Shaw"
iconid:150
id:150
name:"11.1 - Copy of"
relConfig:"ARTEMIS"
releaseDate:"2017-01-05 24:00"
status:"Pending"
undefined:undefined:"jqg33"
_id_:"jqg33"'}

Comment: I can help you only if I can reproduce the problem. You need post the corresponding demo (in jqfiddle for example). Look at demos, which I created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42274864/315935). The demos demonstrates the usage of `lastSelectedData`.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at your demo. It is very helpful. I have been constructing a jsfiddle to try to recreate. So far, I cannot do so. It looks like it must have something to do with the colModel or actual data, which are going to be harder to replicate in a fiddle. I will do my best to get something up and will let you know.